# React Native Expo Jest TypesScript - Cannot use import statement outside module

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, expo, babeljs

I am in the process of converting an expo react-native application to TypeScript and have run into some problems with getting jest tests to run.

package.json

```
{
    "name": "crossword-companion",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start -c",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^5.0.0",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
        "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3",
        "expo": "~46.0.16",
        "expo-camera": "^12.3.0",
        "expo-gl-cpp": "^11.4.0",
        "expo-image-picker": "^13.3.1",
        "expo-status-bar": "^1.4.0",
        "firebase": "^9.12.1",
        "react": "18.0.0",
        "react-dom": "18.0.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.38.0",
        "react-native": "0.69.6",
        "react-native-elements": "^4.0.0",
        "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
        "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
        "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
        "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
        "react-native-web": "^0.18.9"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
        "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
        "@testing-library/react-native": "^9.0.0",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
        "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
        "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "jest": "^26.5.6",
        "jest-expo": "^46.0.1",
        "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
        "typescript": "^4.6.3"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
      presets: [
          "babel-preset-expo",
          ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }],
          "@babel/preset-typescript",
      ],
      plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
  };
};
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    preset: "jest-expo",
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
};
```

The specific error I am getting for the above configuration is for the import statement for a Button from react-native-elements:

CrosswordCreate.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { openCamera, openImageLibrary } from "../../../services";
import { CrosswordImageAnalyzer } from "../../CrosswordImageAnalyzer";

const CrosswordCreate = () => {
    const [image, setImage] = useState({});

    const handleOpenCamera = async () => {
        const myImage = await openCamera();
        setImage(myImage);
    };

    const handleOpenImageLibrary = async (): Promise<void> => {
        const myImage = await openImageLibrary();
        setImage(myImage);
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.viewContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Please select the image of the crossword and clues:</Text>
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button
                    type="clear"
                    buttonStyle={styles.buttons}
                    title="Camera"
                    titleStyle={{ color: "black", marginHorizontal: 20 }}
                    icon={{
                        name: "camera-outline",
                        type: "ionicon",
                        size: 28,
                        color: "black",
                    }}
                    iconContainerStyle={{ margin: "auto" }}
                    testID="crossword-create-open-camera"
                    onPress={handleOpenCamera}
                />
                <Button
                    type="clear"
                    buttonStyle={styles.buttons}
                    title="Library"
                    titleStyle={{ color: "black", marginHorizontal: 20 }}
                    icon={{
                        name: "image-outline",
                        type: "ionicon",
                        size: 28,
                        color: "black",
                    }}
                    iconContainerStyle={{ margin: "auto" }}
                    testID="crossword-create-open-image-library"
                    onPress={handleOpenImageLibrary}
                />
            </View>
            <CrosswordImageAnalyzer source={image} />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    viewContainer: {
        padding: 10,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 24,
        textAlign: "center",
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    buttons: {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        borderColor: "blue",
        borderWidth: 3,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
});

export { CrosswordCreate };
```

And the associated test:
CrosswordCreate.spec.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import { CrosswordCreate } from "../../../../src/components/Crosswords/CrosswordCreate";
import { describe, expect, it } from "@jest/globals";

describe("CrosswordCreate", () => {
    it("should render basic text on load", () => {
        const { getByText } = render(<CrosswordCreate />);
        expect(getByText("Please select the image of the crossword and clues:")).not.toBeNull();
    });
});
```

The specific error is:
[image]

From what I can gather, it looks like an issue with commonjs modules.

I have tried various jest.config.js configurations but to no avail (too many configurations to list here) but always seem to run into the same issue.

I am not using ts-jest but am prepared to if it gets my tests working.

Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same example you have and works fine, but will a different jest.config.js file:

```
// jest.config.js
// Sync object
module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-expo",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": ["ts-jest", {
      tsconfig: {
        jsx: "react"
      }
    }]
  },
  testMatch: [
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).ts?(x)"
  ],
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "!**/coverage/**",
    "!**/node_modules/**",
    "!**/babel.config.js",
    "!**/jest.setup.js"
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "ts",
    "tsx"
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native|react=native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|sentry-expo|native-base)"
  ],
  coverageReporters: [
    "json-summary",
    "text",
    "lcov"
  ]
};
```